# PyTorch ImageFolder: Which Index Does a Folder Get?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, dataset

I want to create a confusion matrix as it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589349/pytorch-confusion-matrix-plot), though I use a different dataset than FashinMNIST. Concretely, I want the axes to contain names such as "banana", "orange", "cucumber", etc. I have a folder where images of bananas, etc. are stored, which I load with [PyTorch's ImageFolder class](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#imagefolder). Now, PyTorch automatically assings the numbers `0` to `9` to my classes (I have 10 classes in total), but I'm not sure whether the label "banana" always gets the same number `0`.

How do I find out, when using the ImageFolder class, which index belongs to which label (subfolder name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `ImageFolder` has attribute `class_to_idx`. Check the [docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#ImageFolder).

```
x = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=path, transform=transform)
print(x.class_to_idx)
```